# STM32 F0 linking with cube library

Tags: linker, arm, stm32

## Little long but neccessary workstation setup

I have downloaded and installed

1. [gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)
2. [STM32CubeF0](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF260612) library (bottom link)
3. prepared makefile, linker script, startup.s (but not relevant to question)

## MVCE

given:

```
export lib_path=/path/to/STM32Cube_FW_F0_V1.5.0/Drivers
export stm_path_1=$lib_path/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
export stm_path_4=$lib_path/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src
export stm_path_2=$lib_path/CMSIS/Include
export stm_path_3=$lib_path/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include
```

and MVCE (from output of running my `make`, formatting changed for SO):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0     \
                  -mthumb -O0 -ggdb3  \
                  -DSTM32F070RB       \
                  -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER    \
                  -DHAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED                    \
                  -DHAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED                      \
                  -DHAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED                     \
                  -DHAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED                      \
                  -I$stm_path_1 -I$stm_path_2 -I$stm_path_3     \
                  -c "$stm_path_4/stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.c"         \
                  -o "stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.o"                     \
```

and three exactly same commands, with except of compiling `stm32f0xx_hal_dma.c`, `stm32f0xx_hal_uart.c` and `stm32f0xx_hal_rcc.c`

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -O0 -ggdb3 -DSTM32F070x6 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED -I$stm_path_1 -I$stm_path_2 -I$stm_path_3 -c "$stm_path_4/stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c" -o "stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -O0 -ggdb3 -DSTM32F070x6 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED -I$stm_path_1 -I$stm_path_2 -I$stm_path_3 -c "$stm_path_4/stm32f0xx_hal_dma.c" -o "stm32f0xx_hal_dma.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -O0 -ggdb3 -DSTM32F070x6 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DHAL_USART_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_DMA_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_GPIO_MODULE_ENABLED -DHAL_RCC_MODULE_ENABLED -I$stm_path_1 -I$stm_path_2 -I$stm_path_3 -c "$stm_path_4/stm32f0xx_hal_rcc.c" -o "stm32f0xx_hal_rcc.o"
```

I have four object files. Now, I obviously have my c sources, but for sake of this question they are irrelevant - if really necessary, You can check even with:

```
// behaviour I'm asking about exists even with:

#include "stm32f0xx.h"
int main(void){}

// being compiled and linked against library.
```

## PROBLEM

Calling linker (I've skipped linking startup.o for clarity):

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostartfiles -o "test.elf" stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.o  stm32f0xx_hal_dma.o  stm32f0xx_hal_rcc.o
```

yields:

```
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1362: multiple definition of `HAL_USART_GetState'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o:stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1362: first defined here
stm32f0xx_hal_dma.o: In function `HAL_USART_GetError':
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1373: multiple definition of `HAL_USART_GetError'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o:stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1373: first defined here
undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1458: undefined reference to `HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1458: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
tm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1461: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o: In function `USART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout':
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1536: undefined reference to `HAL_GetTick'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1546: undefined reference to `HAL_GetTick'
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:1571: undefined reference to `HAL_GetTick'
stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.o: In function `HAL_USART_Transmit_DMA':
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:882: undefined reference to `HAL_DMA_Start_IT'
stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.o: In function `HAL_USART_Receive_DMA':
stm32f0xx_hal_usart.c:945: undefined reference to `HAL_DMA_Start_IT'
```

for several pages.

## What I tried

a) with `__aeabi_uidiv` I've read that linking against libgcc.a helps - but in my case, adding `-Lpath/to/libgcc -lgcc` didn't help. Not sure if I passed those to LDFLAGS or CLFLAGS, but probably for certainty I've added it to both. Didn't help.

b) regarding repeating symbols and/or undefined references - I have tried reordering objects, with no luck. I've checked that functions that linker whines about **are** in those objects.

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: the linker doesnt know where it is or where to find libgcc.  gcc for some reason does know where it is and where to find libgcc.  using gcc for either an assembler or a linker does feel very wrong, but for the case of finding libgcc you might contemplate that.  or just provide the path to the directory where the appropriate (thumb) library lives.  for the rest it is best to start at the top of the list not the bottom or middle to resolve dependencies.  tick them off one at a time.

Comment: or look at the amount of code you are linking in and decide what functions you really need, how many of the dependencies are for code you are not using?  cutting out the unecessary code may be a smaller task or bigger, depends.  these microcontrollers are quite easy to program bare metal, the libraries from the vendors are pretty heavy, you dont "need" them.

Comment: @dwelch - thx, I'm aware that I could do without libraries, just playing with registers and manual, but for this project I wanted to use portable CMSIS solution to familiarize myself with it. But majority of this question regards question why library without any function calls to it (I'm not linking my main.o to any objects from library for example) cannot link on its own, what am I missing.

Comment: these tools dont find stuff on their own they have to be told.  I would for one try the toolchain recommended or sandboxed with the CMSIS stuff you are trying to use, they have to have some tools they tested against.  Then deviate from there or see how they did it.  you should in theory be able to put the library paths and call out the libraries during the link, it is likely to explode into compile and link everything, so either just do that or find each file/library in turn and compile and link it.

Comment: all stuff I gather you already know, it is just a matter of working through it, which IS the educational step you are after or a side effect of the education you are after in using these libraries.  burn the candle at both ends.  work from their sandbox toward the middle for a while then work from a raw toolchain toward the middle.  eventually the knowledge gained will let the two meet.

Comment: you may wish to put the objects into a library and point the linker at that library, otherwise the command line may get quite long.  both ways work, I suspect you just have a lot more files to compile than the four you have so far.

Comment: @dwelch - but that's just exactly what i did "you should in theory be able to put the library paths and call out the libraries during the link, it is likely to explode into compile and link everything, so either just do that or find each file/library in turn and compile and link it". Those 4 files are STM library, in my question i wrote - that even they don't link, given explicit paths (and yes, I've tried linking with my srcs as second step, same results)

Comment: do they not have a build that makes a big library out of everything and not need to do all the individual objects?

Comment: Well, they do have huge library, and if You use it as it is 'recommended' (see my self-answer below) then yes it builds everything. What I wanted to do here is build specific c files from this library on my own and link with them, but it appears it's not so simple as I thought i'd be.

Comment: yeah, as a library the linker only pulls the parts it needs, as objects, not so much.  and building as objects with the rats nest of inter-dependencies you will eventually get the bare minimum built for what you want, but other than the educational aspect did that save you anything.  kind of activity I do often but only sometimes does it make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since none as of now have found an answer for me, here is partial answer for any googlers that might stumble upon this question. Anyone willing to provide better answer is welcome though.

First, it appears that I might have not included -lgcc after all, or rather - I did, but as part of LDFLAGS, which were positioned near front in my call to linker (while it should be near end if not last). I'm not quite sure (haven't found reliable source for this information, if it is true for any given linker) if order of linking is always left to right, but it appears that it is for arm-none-eabi-ld. Thus, any unreferenced symbols found after linking libgcc (that were defined inside it) were actually...undefined. Moving it as last separate argument to LD call fixed undefined references to __arm_div calls etc.

As of now it appears that it's quite impossible to build several separate objects from this library and link against them due to multiple definitions of same symbols. I'll update if I find any defines that control this chaos.

'Recommended' way is to copy two headers from STM library, edit their contents to enable defines, and (sic!) pass same defines in commandline/in makefile, to toolchain's commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this git site](https://github.com/stv0g/stm32cube-gcc) will be helpful for you. It contains a ready to use `Makefile`. It is currently for STM32F4 but if you see an older version (eg. commit  3c310f1) it was for STM32F3. I implemented this `Makefile` for my STM32L0 board.

Based on above mentioned repository I compiled your example without error with the following modification. From a freshly generated Cube initial code for SW4STM32 the necessary files are copied into an empty directory. The necessary files are: `mxconstants.h`, `startup_stm32f070xb.s`, `STM32F051C8Tx_FLASH.ld`, `stm32f0xx_hal_conf.h`. In the last file comment out the definitions which are already defined in your `Makefile` or leave it out from the compiler lines. The current directory is added to the includes (`-I.`). Because an undefined reference an additional file (`system_stm32f0xx.c`) is compiled. Their path is `$lib_path/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/system_stm32f0xx.c`.

When all objects compiled the linker is not called directly `gcc` makes all the work.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -O0 -ggdb3 -Wl,--gc-sections,-lgcc,-lc,-lnosys -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -TSTM32F070RBTx_FLASH.ld startup_stm32f070xb.s stm32f0xx_hal_usart.o stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.o stm32f0xx_hal_dma.o system_stm32f0xx.o main.o -o "test.elf"
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks. I have already solved this, however I looked at Your solution anyways, is always nice to see some other thoughts. I'd rather have more control in makefile, thus I usually separate compilation and linking steps. However if You are certain that it does not compile all objects from stm cube library, I just might give a try when I'll have a moment.

Comment: If you have a little bit different working solution please share it!